# React Component only rendering on some browsers

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of addresses which i have mapped to a list and then rendered on the screen. The issue I am finding is that when the app is deployed it only seems to work on some peoples machines and not others. A few of us have tested on chrome and i cant see the list while others can. While i can not visibly see the list I can still click a selected address so the array is there but it is just no visible.

Below is my code to render the list

```
 $('#addressDropddown').show();

  const listItems =  this.addresses.map((list) =>{
  return(
    <li>
    <p className="addressListButtons" onClick={()=>this.myFunction(myObj, list)}>{list}</p>
    </li>
  )
  })

  //Render the button listdocument.
  ReactDOM.render(<ul>{listItems}</ul>, document.getElementById('addressDropddown'));
```

it is then rendered to the below div

```
    <MDBRow>
             <MDBCol size="3" />
             <MDBCol lg="5" md="12" className="title-left">
             <MDBAnimation className="ex3" id="addressDropddown" type="fadeIn">  
             <div className="ex3" />
             </MDBAnimation>    
            </MDBCol>
             <MDBCol size="3" />
           </MDBRow>
```

i have attached two images of the results on 2 separate pcs. i see the list in one and not the other. 
[Results Not Visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uQUm.jpg)
[Results Visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBGWh.jpg)

Comment: What are the errors you're seeing in the console/developer tools? What browsers are you testing specifically? What browsers do work, and what browser don't work? Also, you're using `jQuery` with `React`?

Comment: Hi, browsers tested where chrome and firefox, there are instances where it works on both and then does not work. I do not get any errors in the console because the actual component and list seems to render ok because i can still click an address from the blank dropdown. I am using jquery to hide and display the component. do you think using setState to show it might work. eg.. this.setState({showAddresses:true})

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that when rendering styling within a component and not through the css it will only be allowed on some browsers and not others.

e.g.

```
document.getElementById("authorisationCheckboxText").style.color = "#ff0000";
```

Comment: Are you saying some browsers support styling via JavaScript and some do not? I doubt it.